# Question about many to many relationship: complete iteration

Tags: php, oop, orm, symfony1, propel

I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables.

I would like to show the elements of a table with the corresponding elements of the other table.

For example:

```
user1->group2
       group5
user2->group1
       group3
       group4
...
```

In an easy and smart way, of course. I'm using php, symfony and propel 1.4.

Any advice or tutorial?

EDIT:

I used a join and I get the objects from the exchange table, so if I iterate it I get:

```
user1->group2
user1->group5
user2->group1
user2->group3
user2->group4
```

But I'm wondering how could i get the group objects from the user objects.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined the relationshop between your `user` and your `group` table in the propel schema, the `User` objects will have a `getGroups()` method. Call this from one `User` and you get a list of all groups this user is joined with. You can do this without doing the join yourself but it will be less efficient, as it will do one extra database query per user. If you do the join when you query for the users, the groups will be cached too.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. would a simple [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) suffice?